# Email from an app, but not use a a pop up controller, just text inside a text box

Tags: iphone, email, uitextview, nsdata

is there any way to send whats in a text view (im trying to make a suggestion box) to my email address?

example

user types in the box " I think you should add twitter support"
then that is sent in the background to my email address example@gmail.com
then a message is popped up on the screen saying "suggestion sent"

just an example of what i mean

Any ideas, tutorial links would be greatly appreciated guys

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in php, asp or many another server side programming language. Depends what your server supports?

Your form action would be a php file that would then process the info sent in the form.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: can you do PHP in on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You can always roll out your own SMTP client code if you don’t want to use the built-in mail composer. But such a solution is not perfect – you have to have an SMTP server (or use an open relay, yuck) and the device has to be online or you have to write some network queue. As for the SMTP client library, quick search returns [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) (no idea if it works at all).

P.S. Do you insist on sending the suggestion by e-mail? Sounds like a simple HTTP POST into a database would do just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I came across that one also. Im going to try it tommorrow.

Any idea if apple lets these sorts of apps through? (apps with background emailers)

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with sending e-mails from your application. (At least that I know of. It’s App Store review – you never know.™)